# discordjs only read messages from specific channel

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I understand the client reads all messages as below

```
client.on("message", (message)=>{});
```

But could you limit the client to read messages only from a specific channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you remove the bot from specific channels or you might have to check the ID or name of the channel and do / don't handle it accordingly. As you already figured out, you have a message object for every message event. You can see in the  [discord.js#message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) docs whats available to you

So you could easily check either the ID of the channel via `if(message.channel.id)`, check the name via `if(message.channel.name)` or pretty much any other available property and handle it to your liking.

As an example for the test channel.

```
if (message.channel.name === 'test')
  return;
```